# Support for butcher block desk

Tags: mounting, support, desk

If I am planning on buying a product such as the one shown [here](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hardwood-Reflections-8-ft-2-in-L-x-2-ft-1-in-D-x-1-5-in-T-Butcher-Block-Countertop-in-Unfinished-European-Walnut-152598HDBW-98/304632201) and to support it using a solution such as the braces shown [here](https://www.countertopbracket.com/Countertop-Supports-Floating-Inside-Wall-Mount-p/fwm.htm) - How often would you place a brace - Is every stud (~16") overkill, can I get away with every other stud (~32"), further? - I don't want the desk to flex under any foreseeable circumstance. (dumb teenager deciding to sit/stand on it for instance).
I can't find any recommendations for a support schedule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you linked states "space the brackets 18 - 24 inches apart" [source 1](https://www.countertopbracket.com/v/vspfiles/install/index.html) [source 2](https://www.countertopbracket.com/default.asp), with the first 4-6" away from the edge. Because you definitely don't want it to flex, even under abuse, I'd err on the side of caution.

With a 8' desk:

- 24" apart would be 4 brackets.
- 18" apart would be 5 brackets.
- 16" apart would also be 5 brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a support frame a bit less than full length and width then just use two strong brackets / supports.

Depends on what you are fixing to as well.